# iOS AVCaptureSession stream micro audio Objective-C++

Tags: c++, ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, objective-c++

*I am currently messing the first time with iOS and Objective-C++. Im coming from C/C++ so please excuse my bad coding in the below examples.*

**I am trying to live stream the microphone audio of my iOS device over tcp, the iOS device is acting as server and sends the data to all clients that connect.**

1. To do so, I am first using `AVCaptureDevice` and `requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio` to request access to the microphone (along with the needed entry in the Info.plist).
2. Then I create a `AVCaptureSession*` using the below function:

   ```
   AVCaptureSession* createBasicARecordingSession(aReceiver* ObjectReceivingAudioFrames){

     AVCaptureSession* s = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

     AVCaptureDevice* aDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
     AVCaptureDeviceInput* aInput = NULL;
     if([aDevice lockForConfiguration:NULL] == YES && aDevice){
         aInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:aDevice error:nil];
         [aDevice unlockForConfiguration];
     }
     else if(!aDevice){
         fprintf(stderr, "[d] could not create device. (%p)\n", aDevice);
         return NULL;
     }
     else{
         fprintf(stderr, "[d] could not lock device.\n");
         return NULL;
     }

     if(!aInput){
         fprintf(stderr, "[d] could not create input.\n");
         return NULL;
     }

     AVCaptureAudioDataOutput* aOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
     dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_queue_create("aQueue", NULL);

     if(!aOutput){
         fprintf(stderr, "[d] could not create output.\n");
         return NULL;
     }

     [aOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:ObjectReceivingAudioFrames queue:aQueue];
     // the below line does only work on macOS
     //aOutput.audioSettings = settings;

     [s beginConfiguration];
     if([s canAddInput:aInput]){
         [s addInput:aInput];
     }
     else{
         fprintf(stderr, "[d] could not add input.\n");
         return NULL;
     }
     if([s canAddOutput:aOutput]){
         [s addOutput:aOutput];
     }
     else{
         fprintf(stderr, "[d] could not add output.\n");
         return NULL;
     }
     [s commitConfiguration];

     return s;

   }
   ```
3. The `aReceiver*` class (?) is defined below and receives the audio frames provided by the `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput*` object. The frames are stored inside a `std::vector`.

*(im adding the code as image as I could not get it formatted right...)*
[image]
[image]

4. Then I start the `AVCaptureSession*` using `[audioSession start]`
5. When a tcp client connects I first create a `AudioConverterRef` and two `AudioStreamBasicDescription` to convert the audio frames to AAC, see below:

   ```
   AudioStreamBasicDescription asbdIn, asbdOut;
   AudioConverterRef converter;

   asbdIn.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
   //asbdIn.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
   asbdIn.mFormatFlags = 12;
   asbdIn.mSampleRate = 44100;
   asbdIn.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
   asbdIn.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
   asbdIn.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
   //asbdIn.mBytesPerFrame = (asbdIn.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * asbdIn.mBitsPerChannel;
   asbdIn.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
   asbdIn.mBytesPerPacket = asbdIn.mBytesPerFrame;
   asbdIn.mReserved = 0;

   asbdOut.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
   asbdOut.mFormatFlags = 0;
   asbdOut.mSampleRate = 44100;
   asbdOut.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
   asbdOut.mFramesPerPacket = 1024;
   asbdOut.mBitsPerChannel = 0;
   //asbdOut.mBytesPerFrame = (asbdOut.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * asbdOut.mBitsPerChannel;
   asbdOut.mBytesPerFrame = 0;
   asbdOut.mBytesPerPacket = asbdOut.mBytesPerFrame;
   asbdOut.mReserved = 0;

   OSStatus err = AudioConverterNew(&asbdIn, &asbdOut, &converter);
   ```
6. Then I create a `AudioBufferList*` to store the encoded frames:

   ```
   while(audioInput.locked){ // audioInput is my aReceiver*
       usleep(0.2 * 1000000);
   }
   audioInput.locked = true;

   UInt32 RequestedPackets = 8192;
   //AudioBufferList* aBufferList = (AudioBufferList*)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList));
   AudioBufferList* aBufferList = static_cast<AudioBufferList*>(calloc(1, offsetof(AudioBufferList, mBuffers) + (sizeof(AudioBuffer) * 1)));
   aBufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;

   aBufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = asbdIn.mChannelsPerFrame;
   aBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = static_cast<void*>(calloc(RequestedPackets, asbdIn.mBytesPerFrame));
   aBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = asbdIn.mBytesPerFrame * RequestedPackets;
   ```
7. Then I go through the frames stored in the `std::vector` mentioned earlier and pass them to `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer()`. After conversion, i concat all encoded frames into one `NSMutableData` which I then `write()` to the socket connected to the client.

   ```
   long aBufferListSize = audioInput.aBufferList.size();

   while(aBufferListSize > 0){

      err = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(converter, feedAFrames, static_cast<void*>(&audioInput.aBufferList[audioInput.aBufferList.size() - aBufferListSize]), &RequestedPackets, aBufferList, NULL);

      NSMutableData* encodedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
      long encodedDataLen = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < aBufferList->mNumberBuffers; i++){

          Float32* frame = (Float32*)aBufferList->mBuffers[i].mData;
          [encodedData appendBytes:frame length:aBufferList->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize];
          encodedDataLen += aBufferList->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize;

      }

      unsigned char* encodedDataBytes = (unsigned char*)[encodedData bytes];

      fprintf(stderr, "[d] got %li encoded bytes to send...\n", encodedDataLen);
      long bytes = write(Client->GetFD(), encodedDataBytes, encodedDataLen);
      fprintf(stderr, "[d] written %li of %li bytes.\n", bytes, encodedDataLen);

      usleep(0.2 * 1000000);

      aBufferListSize--;

   }

   audioInput.aBufferList.clear();

   audioInput.locked = false;
   ```
8. Below is the `feedAFrames()` callback used in the `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer()` call:

*(again this is an image of the code, same reason as above)*
[image]

Step 5 to 7 are repeated until the tcp connection is closed.

---

Each step runs without any noticeable error (I know I could include way better error handling here), and I do get data out of step 3 and 7. However it does not seem to be AAC what comes out at the end.

As im rather new to all of this, im really not sure what my error is, im sure there are several things I made wrong. It is kind of hard to find suitable example code of what I am trying to do, and the above is the best I could come up with until now with all that I have found paired with the apple dev documentation.

I hope someone might take some time to explain me what I did wrong and how I can get this to work. Thanks for reading until here!

Comment: Some impressions: there's a lot going on here - what's wrong with the AAC coming from the `AudioConverter`? You shouldn't sleep in `didOutputSamples`, `asbdIn` should be gotten from the first sample buffer you see. `AVAudioConverter` can be a little friendlier (but doesn't work with sample buffers) & finally, it's not raw tcp but something like https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift can stream microphone audio from your phone.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response! FFmpeg and ffplay can't decode the AAC that comes out, instead it states `invalid data found`. I sleep in didOutputSamples to not work on the `std::vector` while frames stored in there are processed for conversion, but I see that this may not be a good practice like it is at the moment. Do you mean that `AVAudioConverter` does not work with the output of `CMSampleBufferRef` from step 3? Can you describe how `AVAudioConverter` can be friendlier? What does that mean?